# Cant access wsdl file after migrating from websphere to tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, wsdl

I have been migrating an application from a websphere server to tomcat. But now I discovered a problem with accessing the wsdl file. The file is in the correct folder but I cant access it within the code even though it works in websphere. What do I need to change after migrating to tomcat?

Java-class:

```
    //
// Generated By:JAX-WS RI IBM 2.1.1 in JDK 6 (JAXB RI IBM JAXB 2.1.3 in JDK 1.6)
//

package iseries.wsbeans.bit05;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.ws.Service;
import javax.xml.ws.WebEndpoint;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceClient;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceFeature;

@WebServiceClient(name = "BIT05", targetNamespace = "http://bit05.wsbeans.iseries", wsdlLocation = "WEB-INF/wsdl/BIT05.wsdl")
public class BIT05
    extends Service
{

    private final static URL BIT05_WSDL_LOCATION;

    static {
        URL url = null;

        try {
            url = new URL("file:./WEB-INF/wsdl/BIT05.wsdl");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        BIT05_WSDL_LOCATION = url;
    }

    public BIT05(URL wsdlLocation, QName serviceName) {
        super(wsdlLocation, serviceName);
    }

    public BIT05() {
        super(BIT05_WSDL_LOCATION, new QName("http://bit05.wsbeans.iseries", "BIT05"));
    }
```

Log:

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Failed to access the WSDL at: file:./WEB-INF/wsdl/BIT05.wsdl. It failed with: 
    Got .\WEB-INF\wsdl\BIT05.wsdl (The system cannot find the path specified) while opening stream from file:./WEB-INF/wsdl/BIT05.wsdl.
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.tryWithMex(Unknown Source)
```

Any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
url = new URL("file:./WEB-INF/wsdl/BIT05.wsdl");
```

Try with:

```
url = BIT05.class.getClassLoader().getResource("wsdl/BIT05.wsdl");
```

It's always better to use classloader or `ServletContext` if any rather than directly filesystem when the file is in your classpath.

Comment: I managed to use another variation of this solution. Just in case someone ends up with the same problem. I changed it to: url = iseries.wsbeans.bit05.BIT05.class.getResource("BIT05.wsdl"); (could not use "this" in static) and placed the BIT05.wsdl file inside the same folder as the java class. It just seemed to be impossible to access the files in another folder. Anyway, this solution worked so thank you and I will mark it as correct :)

Comment: Right, I totally forgot you were in a static block. I'll update my answer for more visibility of your comment.